How to use a proxy service with chrome devtools protocol via chromote R package wrapper
I want traffic to go through a proxy service, but I'm not sure how to do this using the chromote R package wrapper.
This code returns the public IP address without using a proxy:
b <- chromote::ChromoteSession$new()

b$Page$navigate("https://ipinfo.io/ip")

b$Runtime$evaluate("document.body.innerText")$result$value

b$close()

Adding the --proxy-server argument doesn't return the proxy IP as expected:
proxy <- "101.51.139.219:8180"
chromote::set_chrome_args(
  glue::glue(
    "--proxy-server={proxy}"
  )
)

chromote::get_chrome_args()

b <- chromote::ChromoteSession$new()

b$Page$navigate("https://ipinfo.io/ip")

b$Runtime$evaluate("document.body.innerText")$result$value

b$close()


The following should work if run in a new R session and the proxy is valid:
proxy <- "101.51.139.219:8180"
chromote::set_chrome_args(
  glue::glue(
    "--proxy-server={proxy}"
  )
)

chromote::get_chrome_args()

b <- chromote::ChromoteSession$new()

b$Page$navigate("https://ipinfo.io/ip")

b$Runtime$evaluate("document.body.innerText")$result$value

b$close()

ChromoteSession$new() actually creates a new Chrome object if none exist using chromote::Chrome$new(). The arg for setting a proxy is passed to Chrome$new() and thus needs to be set prior to that function call or passed directly to Chrome$new().
